# could not find function "clusplot"

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

this is my instruction : `clusplot(pa,as.factor(kmeans(pa,3)$cluster))` 
`pa` : is my database (parkinson)

the result should be 2 graph :

The first represents the basis of allocation
The second represents the silhouette of each group of individuals

but

Whenever I use the `clusplot` function in my code, I get this Error: `could not find function "clusplot"`

What should I do?

Comment: You did install and load the `cluster` package, right?

Answer (score 2):

As Stephan says, it looks like the `cluster` package isn't loaded.

Make sure it's installed with:

```
install.packages("cluster")
```

And don't forget to load it with:

```
library("cluster")
```